# Fire event when a property or variable changes value

Tags: c#, events, variables, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I want to add more functionality to a project I have that makes use a number of classes packaged in the NET Framework. These same classes provide a number of properties which can be quite useful adapting the functionality of my project, however one thing that these classes lack is Events.

If each property had a appropriate event that would fire whenever the value of such property changed, I could then assign a event handler that would act based on those properties value.

I made a sample case bellow to illustrate my goal in the most simpler way I could think off.

> **Sample case:**
>
> The `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class ([Socket on MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)) has a property
>   named `Connected` that basically returns true if the socket is
>   connected to a specified end point otherwise returns false.
>
> What I would like to accomplish is simple. I would like to keep this
>   property under "watch" and when the value of it changes, fire a event.

Doing that to one of my own classes it would be simple although a bit tiresome using the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx), simply because always that my code changed the value of the property I would have to fire the event manually. Unfortunately, to best of my knowledge, not even this kind of procedure can be applied to the existing `Socket` class distributed within NET Framework.

Well, this question is becoming quite extensive, sorry, but I hope it gave an insight to my goal.

Now simply putting it, I want to watch the `Connected` property of the `Socket` class and when the value of it changes, fire an event. And if it would be possible to also use such approach to watch variables as well properties, it would be awesome, not just for me, but for everyone who stumbles across this question on SO.

A simple and lightweight approach is preferred of course, but most of all, I want to understand how it can be done, so in the future I can apply it in mass scale to other classes.

I realize I'm asking a lot. Many thanks.

*Any questions just ask.*

Comment: I'm assuming you essentially want to attach some sort of Observer based pattern onto an existing, unalterable class (like the socket example)?  If so, would you check for value changes say, every main thread loop?  Background thread with timers?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: That could be one approach. I'm looking at any available ways of doing it, trying them out myself and choose the most simple and light.

Comment: I must be missing something.  I don't see how the posted observer patterns would help with monitoring the change of state of an arbitrary member of a non-modifiable class/member (such as `Socket.Connected`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'm not seeing it at first either, but I have to give it a shoot. Maybe there is something I'm not seeing.

Comment: I think the Reactive Extensions (RX) may be able to do this.  I'm not sure (haven't found a good sample yet) but I think you can use it to wire up lambda expressions to point to a value and periodically check it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg577609

Comment: Ahh, nevermind.  I just misread something and Rx is just the observer patterns already referenced (part of the BCL) I think.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: No worry. Matter of fact I'm starting to think that .NET classes don't allow easy "observation" of properties. That has got me wondering about doing something from scratch.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a basic class that should get you started.  I'm sure a fully functional, production-ready, thread-safe class would require a bit more work, plus you need to implement your own strategy for when to poll for value changes.

```
public class TargettedObserver<T>
{
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T> EqualityComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    private Func<T> ValueTarget;
    private T OldValue;

    public event ObservedValueChangedEventHandler<T> ValueChanged;

    public TargettedObserver(Func<T> valueTarget)
    {
        this.ValueTarget = valueTarget;
        OldValue = ObtainCurrentValue();
    }

    public bool CheckValue()
    {
        T oldValue = OldValue;
        T newValue = ObtainCurrentValue();

        bool hasValueChanged = CompareValues(oldValue, newValue);

        if (hasValueChanged)
        {
            OldValue = newValue;
            NotifyValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        }

        return hasValueChanged;
    }

    private void NotifyValueChanged(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        var valueChangedEvent = ValueChanged;
        if (valueChangedEvent != null)
            valueChangedEvent(this, new ObservedValueChangedEventArgs<T>(oldValue, newValue));
    }

    private static bool CompareValues(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        return !EqualityComparer.Equals(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    private T ObtainCurrentValue()
    {
        return ValueTarget();
    }
}
```

And the event handling:

```
public class ObservedValueChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T OldValue { get; private set; }
    public T NewValue { get; private set; }

    public ObservedValueChangedEventArgs(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        this.OldValue = oldValue;
        this.NewValue = newValue;
    }
}

public delegate void ObservedValueChangedEventHandler<T>(TargettedObserver<T> observer, ObservedValueChangedEventArgs<T> eventArgs);
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Socket MySocket;
    private static TargettedObserver<bool> SocketConnectedObserver;

    public void Main()
    {
        MySocket = new Socket();
        SocketConnectedObserver = new TargettedObserver<bool>(() => MySocket.Connected);
        SocketConnectedObserver.ValueChanged += ReportSocketConnectedStateChanged;
        PerformSocketConnection();

        MainThread.Invoke(PollSocketValue);
    }

    private void PollSocketValue()
    {
        SocketConnectedObserver.CheckValue();
        MainThread.Invoke(PollSocketValue);
    }

    private void ReportSocketConnectedStateChanged(TargettedObserver<bool> observer, ObservedValueChangedEventArgs<bool> eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket connection state changed!  OldValue: " + eventArgs.OldValue + ", NewValue: " + eventArgs.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Notice the constructor takes a simple lambda expression that can evaluate the value you're wanting to observe.

Also note that `MainThread.Invoke` is just a pseudocode to show it polling for a change on every main thread loop.  I'm sure there are nicer strategies (background thread with a timer interval) for example that could be implemented in a nice, reusable way.  Still more work to be done in terms of deregistering the observer.  Could probably make some nice factory methods or lambda delegates so you don't need to keep the TargettedObserver instance floating around and reduce the amount of wiring/manual code.  But at least this should be a start.

Comment: This seems quite a good head start.
I'm thinking of building a class based on yours that will manage the polling and checking of all properties I assign to it on a single background thread. I have quite a few to manage and that way a single thread would more than needed to poll and check all of them.
Also I might change a bit of the checking method to detect when a properties host object has been disposed or set as null, and on such event do not poll or check it's assigned properties, and remove them form the check list.
Sounds like a plan. Thanks for the help Chris Sinclair.

Comment: Ohh by the way forgot to mention. Your code so far so good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is an implementation of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  Something like [this `Observable<T>` implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85928/Observable-Automatically-Notify-Property-Owner-Whe) might work.

See also the [`IObserver<T>` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) in .NET 4:

> The `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>` interfaces provide a generalized
>   mechanism for push-based notification. The `IObservable<T>` interface represents the class that
>   sends notifications (the provider); the `IObserver<T>` interface
>   represents the class that receives them (the observer). `T` represents
>   the class that provides the notification information.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'm trying your approach now.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would guess that the `IObervable<T>`implementation would only work for my own classes, and not those unalterable classes like `Socket` within NET Framework. Could you provide an example of it with the Socket class for instance?

Comment: I'm not sure about the CodeProject implementation either  (having never actually used it), but the .NET 4 classes are specifically billed as proxy classes that allow observation of an existing class without having to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The CodeProject article makes the same claim.